# Facebook app - no "Installable to"

Tags: facebook, tabs

I am creating a small Facebook application for pages (not profiles).
I can see in many tutorials, to allow the application to be added to a page, as a tab, you need to select in the app settings:
Authentification -> Authentification Settings -> Installable to : Facebook pages.

I think the menu is evolving since different tutorials show different locations.
Form the screenshots, I can tell this page is for me Facebook Integration.
In it I can see the Page Tabs section, but there is no "Installable to" option.
Not here nor anywhere else.

That really drives me crazy, I have wasted almost half day on this, I just want to click this option ... :(

If anyone can tip me on this my appreciation will be infinite!

Thank you,
Aurelien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to add my app to a new tab:

1. You need to create a profile for the page admin! If you didn't, on the top right of Facebook page you should have a link 'Create Your Profile'. It doesn't make sense to me but ...
2. Go to this link (thanks ifaour):https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token
3. Got to your http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=YOUR_APP_ID and add the app to your page

Answer (score 0):

That option is no longer exists (at least in the settings page).

What you can do is getting the page admin to authorize your application and then post on his behalf OR get the page access token (also needs the admin authorization) by asking for the [`manage_pages`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) permission.

*A quick note when reading tutorials about facebook development, check the date of the article because most of articles are outdated!*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have a page where I am testing this (I am admin). If I try to install the app it just asks me to create a profile(I filled all 'tab' values in the app settings) ... I am not sure exactly where I should ask for the manage_pages permission but I will have a look. However I am afraid I have to pass the add app first. All this is really confusing for me.

Comment: UPDATE: I checked your link, and went to this URL: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token. I gave the authorization. If I go to the app page, I can see the 'Remove App' link, so I guess it has been added, but I still don't have it in my apps list, so I don't know how I can add it to a tab. Any idea? Sorry to bother again, I am actively looking for answers on my side too ...